# Linux mailserver with MySQL/virtual users

Tags: linux, email, smtp

I've been working with postfix and stuff earlier, but postfix has the negative point of *insane* configuration, etc.. Although I got it working in older projects, I don't want to use it anymore.

I'm looking for the lightest and easiest linux mailserver software allowing me:

- multiple virtual domains and users via database
- IMAP
- transport layer security, preferably with PFS
- spam filter and anti-virus
- easily letting me combine with or better, has already integrated, SMTP (also with secure layer)
- quota is nice to have but not a must-have

Comment: The best I haveever come up with is a good set of instructions.  It includes postfix, which I would also like to avoid, but it has instruction and I got it working.  [instructions][1]


  [1]: https://lelutin.ca/posts/installing_postfix_-_clamav_-_spamassassin_-_dovecot_-_postfixadmin_on_debian_squeeze/

Answer (score 1):

Try [iRedMail](http://www.iredmail.org/).

> Works on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Scientific Linux, Debian,
>   Ubuntu, FreeBSD, OpenBSD. Since 2007.

it is easy to install, and most of the configurations are automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Just found https://mailinabox.email/

> Take back control of your email with this easy-to-deploy mail server
>   in a box.

Based on open source programs, including DNS tools and DNSSEC.